# How to reduce the PDF file size of MPDF

Tags: php, pdf, compression, mpdf

I am creating a 15 to 20 pages PDF using MPDF on Form Submission. PDF file size comes around 2.5MB. Is there a way to reduce the file size below 1 MB?

Since the SetCompression() default value is True, I tried setting this to False and checked the file size of PDF. There is no change in file size.
I tried SetCompression() and still no luck.
I even reduced the PDF to 3 pages, size sill comes around 1.5MB. 
Is there any other way to reduce the file size?

Can someone help me with this?

Below is the link for the code which I used.

```
[https://pastebin.com/fvvADjxh][1]
```

https://pastebin.com/fvvADjxh

Comment: Just a not that the default for compression is true anyway (from [manual](https://mpdf.github.io/reference/mpdf-functions/setcompression.html))

Comment: Thanks for the response. I tested by having the SetCompression() to false but still, the file size is the same. 
I even tried reducing the content and reduced the PDF to 3 pages, size sill comes around 1.5MB. Is there any other way to reduce the file size?

Comment: Can you share an example of your current result? The heavy things are simply images I guess.

Comment: There is only 1 image in the PDF which is less than 200kb. But I have 15 pages in PDF which is nothing but content.

Comment: You don't want to share an example?

Comment: You want to see the code for generating PDF? I didnt understand

Comment: You say that you create a PDF with only one image (200kb) while the rest is just content. I'm curious what type of content blows the size up to 2,5MB then. For sure this requires you to provide an example PDF output. And for sure you're also welcome to provide the code you use to create the PDF. As more information you offer as more there is a chance that we can help you.

Comment: Here is the link for code: https://pastebin.com/fvvADjxh

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Compress your images.

Image `raven_tours_treks_logo.jpg` in your code is 619,75 kB. The file contains it twice - by compressing it correctly, you can save a megabyte or so.

`raven_tours_treks.jpg` has almost a megabyte. It can safely be reduced to 80kB or so - another megabyte saved.

Comment: Hi Finwe,

Thanks for the suggestion. I never thought of this. I have compressed all the images in the PDF and I am able to reduce the size from 2.3MB to 550KB. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try whether `pdftk` compression significantly reduces the size of your PDF file.

```
pdftk file1.pdf output file2.pdf compress
```

If you are satisfied with the results, I can enhance our [object-oriented PHP pdftk wrapper](https://github.com/gmitirol/toolkit-pdftk) with the capability to compress PDF files.

Comment: I am looking for a solution in mPDF. Maybe if there are no solutions, then I will look for alternatives. Thank you!